# AlarmManager schedule Alarm on application start

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm, android-os-handler

this is a very dumb question and I still cannot figure out how does `AlarmManager` work in Android. Suppose I want to schedule a repeating task every half an hour. I want to schedule it at activity `onCreate()`. I do something like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, alarmIntent);
}
```

Now my question is how does OS knows that this alarm **has already been scheduled**? I mean it is not scheduling a new one every time activity creates, is it? Otherwise, after 10 activity launches I would get alarm every three minutes and not half an hour. Please, any Android guru, explanation about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is how does OS knows that this alarm has already been scheduled?

AFAIK, it looks for an existing alarm for an equivalent `PendingIntent`. Here, by "equivalent `PendingIntent`", I mean:

- the same operation (e.g., `getBroadcast()`)
- the same ID (second parameter to `getBroadcast()`)
- an equivalent `Intent`

Here, by "equivalent `Intent`", I mean that they match on all the routing information, which in your case is the `ComponentName` generated from `this` and `AlarmReceiver.class`. Extras, in particular, do not count for equivalence here.

Comment: So it just skipping scheduling the alarm or it is cancelling previous?

Comment: @LuciusHipan: It should be cancelling the previous alarm, just as if you had called `cancel()`. Since `cancel()` takes a `PendingIntent` as the sole identifier of what alarm to cancel, there can only be one alarm per `PendingIntent`.

Comment: So this means, if I have this in OnCreate() scheduled for 10 minutes, but I open application again it 8 minutes, the alarm will not be triggered in 2 minutes from there?

Comment: @LuciusHipan: I would not expect it to. I have not tried this specific scenario recently and so I forget whether Android does something unexpected here.

Comment: I've just tried, and it behaves as I said... It is sad that nowhere in docs appears the issue. I wonder how many developers faced unexact alarm-based events. Thanks for your help.